# Scaling TikZ picture based on text size around the environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize

I'd like to scale a Ti*k*Z picture based on font size surrounding the environment.

For example...

```
\documentclass{standalone}                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                             
\usepackage{tikz}      
                                                                                                                             
\begin{document}                                                                                                             
                                                             
{                                                                                                                            
\begin{tikzpicture}                                          
  \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);                                                                                             
  \node at (0,0) {Hello world};                      
\end{tikzpicture}                                                                                                            
}                                 
                                                                                                                             
{                                                                                                                            
\Huge                             
\begin{tikzpicture}                                                                                                          
  \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);                   
  \node at (0,0) {Hello world};                                                                                              
\end{tikzpicture}                                  
}                                                                                                                            
                                                   
{                                                                                                                            
\tiny                                                                                                                        
\begin{tikzpicture}      
  \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);                                                                                             
  \node at (0,0) {Hello world};                                                                                              
\end{tikzpicture}      
}                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                             
\end{document}
```

I expect the second and third of these images to look like the first one, but scaled. Is it possible to use the `x=` and `y=` keys on the Ti*k*Z picture environment to allow for scaling of the image relative to the current font size?

---

## EDIT

After a little more work I came up with the following...

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{printlen}

\newlength{\textsizenow}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\refreshtextsizenow}{%
  \setlength{\textsizenow}{\f@size pt}
  }
\makeatother

\newcommand{\example}{%
  \refreshtextsizenow
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\textsizenow,y=\textsizenow]
    \draw (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
    \node at (0,0) {Hello world};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\begin{document}

{
\Huge
\example
}

{
\huge
\example
}

{
\LARGE
\example
}

{
\Large
\example
}

{
\large
\example
}

{
\normalsize
\example
}

{
\small
\example
}

{
\footnotesize
\example
}

{
\scriptsize
\example
}

{
\tiny
\example
}

\end{document}
```

It uses `\f@size` to set a length before each image is drawn. I then use the `x=...,y=...` keys to set the coordinate size. This seems to get *close* to what I am trying to do. However, if the code above is compiled, the horizontal spacing between the text and the sides shrink as the text size gets smaller. The vertical spacing seems somewhat consistent. I expect both the horizontal and vertical spacing to stay the same. Is this possible to fix?

Comment: I have two problems with your code: 1) It can‘t compile. Please fix it. 2) What does it display? How can a set of circles or their fragments yield something readable as text? A screenshot may clarify. Please EDIT your question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: 1. Done. 2. It displays an image. Doesn't matter what image. The image can be a rectangle for all it matters. It displays text within the `\node` at the end of the picture environment.

Comment: I have updated the code to be much simpler, but the question still remains the same.

Comment: The usual approach is using [scale=3, transform shape] together. scale scales, transform shape cares for other geometrical relationships. See the manual for details. To adjust font sizes the way you describe you may need some of the if-related packages. Try in your search engine: ctan if .

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe you can just use `em` as unit in your Ti*k*Z environment which is a unit that is relative to the font size.

Comment: `\makeatletter\tikzset{xy fontsize/.style={x=\f@size pt, y=\f@size pt}}\makeatother` and then just use `xy fontsize` as an option to the `tikzpicture`. Fonts at different sizes aren't just scaled versions of each other. Try `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{pgffor}\begin{document}\foreach\SIZE in{\tiny,\scriptsize,\footnotesize,\small,{},\large,\Large,\LARGE,\huge,\Huge}{ \pgfmathprint{width("\SIZE Foobar")/(height("\SIZE Foobar")+depth("\SIZE Foobar"))}}\end{document}` and you will get ratios roughly between 4.0 and 6.0. That's why some text protrudes more over your rectangle than others.

Comment: @JasperHabicht this produces the same result as my `f@size` solution, but much simpler!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For font size dependent images, the following options can be used

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em,y=1em]
    \draw (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
    \node at (0,0) {Hello world};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This sets the coordinate system so `1` is actually `1em`. `em's are a unit whose value are relative to the current font size. Considerations such as font family must also be taken into account as kerning or symbol sizes may differ from one font family to another.